# How change name to emails sent out my outlook.com account, not Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: outlook.com

I want change my Outlook.com account name when people get emails from me.

I'm talking about just outlook.com online, not Microsoft Outlook software you install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps

1. Click on your avatar in the upper right corner and choose `My account`.

[image: My Account]

After that, you will see your profile.

2. Click on `More actions`>>`Edit profile`>>`Edit name` and **enter the name you want to change to**.